# Find and replace AppleScript not writing file

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an AppleScript for the first time in order to change all the event titles in an ics file quickly. I'm using Automator to do this with a simple "Run AppleScript" service.

When I right click the ics file and activate the service, it runs without changing anything. When I run it from Automator it just returns false, which I assume means it failed to write to the file.

```
on run {inputfile}
    set filedata to inputfile as string
    set filedata to replaceText("Title 1", "Title 2", filedata)
    writeTextToFile(filedata, inputfile, true)
end run

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to find
    set textString to text items of textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replace
    set textString to "" & textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return textString
end replaceText

on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        
        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string
        
        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        
        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        
        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile
        
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true
        
        -- Handle a write error
    on error
        
        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile
```

Is it Line 2 where the problem is? I thought you don't need to specify the file path since the service should be inputting the file.

Comment: You have to specify the (full) file path and consider that `inputfile` is a list even if there is only one item.

Comment: In the posted script I am not seeing where you are actually opening the file, so using the variable `theOpenedFile` is going to throw an error.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you are not actually _opening_ the target _file_ to be _written_ to, you also are not _reading_ the target _file_ into a _variable_ in order for the `replaceText` _handler_ to actually replace the _text_. Have a look at the `writeTextToFile` _handler_ [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html) -- To `read` the _file_ you could change `set filedata to inputfile as string` to: `set filedata to (read inputfile as string)`

Comment: Additionally, as written, your **AppleScript** _code_ can only process a single _file_ passed to it at a time. So, as written, if you pass it more than one _file_ at a time it will error even if you make the suggested corrections to the existing _code_. You also have not included any _error handling_ if you accidentally pass it a _folder_, multiple _files_, or non **ics** _files_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **macOS High Sierra** with the **Automator** *Service* set to **Receives selected [files or folders] in [Finder]** and a single **Run AppleScript** *action*, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me to modify an **ICS** *file*:

- Note that as coded it can handle multiple selected files and only valid **ICS** *files* can be modified.

```applescript
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with anItem in input
        set thisFile to anItem
        if (get {folder, kind} of (info for thisFile)) is {false, "ICS file"} then
            set fileData to (read thisFile)
            set newFileData to replaceText("Title 1", "Title 2", fileData)
            writeTextToFile(newFileData, thisFile, true)
        end if
    end repeat
end run

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to find
    set textString to text items of textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replace
    set textString to "" & textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return textString
end replaceText

on writeTextToFile(theText, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        -- Convert the file to a string
        set theFile to theFile as string
        -- Open the file for writing
        set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        -- Clear the file if content should be overwritten
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        -- Write the new content to the file
        write theText to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        -- Close the file
        close access theOpenedFile
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing was successful
        return true
        -- Handle a write error
    on error
        -- Close the file
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        -- Return a boolean indicating that writing failed
        return false
    end try
end writeTextToFile
```

Comment: user3439894, this code works perfectly. Many thanks to you for fixing it. I can save a lot of time changing names now.